# Where does Duplicati keep its log files?

Tags: windows, logging, duplicati

I searched

- C:\ProgramData\Duplicati
- C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming (No Duplicati)
- C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Duplicati
- https://www.duplicati.com/articles/
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=duplicati+logs&ia=web
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/duplicati/log$20directory%7Csort:relevance
- https://forum.duplicati.com/search?q=log%20file
- C:\Program Files\Duplicati 2

I saw an error about a file a few days ago I need to investigate, but the log in the web interface only shows the latest 25 messages or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Duplicati help page](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/blob/master/Duplicati/CommandLine/help.txt) indicates that logging is disabled by default, but the path to the log file can be viewed by executing the following command:

`duplicati.commandline.exe help logging`

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find the logs myself. It turns out the logs that are shown in the web interface are not stored in text files but in the .sqlite files under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Duplicati`.

First install sqlite, which is just `choco install sqlite` in an administrator shell if you're using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Then you can open the .sqlite file with `sqlite3 <filename>`. You can see the schema with `.schema`. The log entries are in the tables called "LogData" and "RemoteOperation". You can, for example, list the first ten entries of the local log with `select * from LogData limit 10`. See [sqlite's documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for further information on the syntax.

If you'd like to dump the log entries to a text file in order to be able to use other tools to process it, see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199221/238431) about changing the output mode to CSV and directing it to a file.

Depending on why you need the logs, you may find it easier to go through the web interface. At first I thought I needed to look through the remote logs for errors, because the general logs seemed useless. But it turns out that, at least in Duplicati 2.0's web interface, you can click on each log entry to expand it. I found the errors I was looking for under the general log that way.